# Numbers with similar powers

Tags: code-golf, primes, permutations

Given an integer ***p > 1***, find the smallest integer ***q > p*** such that the list of exponents in the prime factorization of ***q*** is the same of that of ***p***, no matter the order or the value of the prime factors.

### Examples

The prime factorization of ***p = 20*** is ***2<sup>2</sup> x 5<sup>1</sup>***. The smallest integer greater than ***p*** with identical exponents in its prime factorization is ***q = 28 = 2<sup>2</sup> x 7<sup>1</sup>***.

The prime factorization of ***p = 2500*** is ***2<sup>2</sup> x 5<sup>4</sup>***. The smallest integer greater than ***p*** with identical exponents in its prime factorization is ***q = 2704 = 2<sup>4</sup> x 13<sup>2</sup>***.

### Rules

- The input is guaranteed to be an integer greater than 1.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
Input | Output
------+-------
2     | 3
20    | 28
103   | 107
256   | 6561
768   | 1280
2500  | 2704
4494  | 4510
46552 | 46584
75600 | 105840
```

Comment: Just for reference, this is [A081761](http://oeis.org/A081761) in the OEIS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 10 bytes

```
§ḟ¤≡ȯÖLgp→
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkHtiffGjpsaiQ9v@H1r@cMf8Q0sedS48sf7wNJ/0gkdtk/7//2/EZWTAZWhgzGVkasZlbmYBpA0MuExMLE24TMxMTY24zE3NDAwA)

#### Explantion

```
§ḟ       →     Find the first number starting from the input + 1 such that...
        p        The prime factorisation
       g         with equal elements grouped together
    ȯÖL          and sorted by length of groups
  ¤≡             has the same shape as the above applied to the input.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 61 bytes

```
(f[x_]:=Sort[Last/@FactorInteger@x];s=#;While[f@++s!=f@#];s)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fbvtfIy26Ij7WyjY4v6gk2iexuETfwS0xuSS/yDOvJDU9tcihIta62FbZOjwjMyc1Os1BW7tY0TbNQRkoqqn2P6AoM69EwSE92sjUwCD2PwA)

*-4 bytes from @Misha Lavrov*

Comment: A more concise way of writing such a `While` loop is `s=#;While[f@++s!=f@#];s`.

Comment: You can replace `f[x_]` with `f@x_` to save a byte.

Comment: Or even go the composition-salad route of defining `f=Last/@#&@*FactorInteger/*Sort`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer.

```
ÆEḟ0Ṣ
,Ç€Eð2#Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//w4ZF4bifMOG5ogosw4figqxFw7AyI@G5qv///zI1MDA)

Comment: It took you _almost_ 3 minutes. ;)

Comment: [-1 byte by using `2#Ṫ` instead](https://tio.run/##AScA2P9qZWxsef//w4ZF4bifMOG5ogosw4figqxFw7AyI@G5qv///zI1MDA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 15 bytes

```
fqFmShMrPd8,QTh
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqFmShMrPd8%2CQTh&input=20&test_suite_input=2%0A20%0A103%0A256%0A768%0A2500%0A4494%0A46552%0A75600&debug=0)** or **[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=fqFmShMrPd8%2CQTh&input=20&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=2%0A20%0A103%0A256%0A768%0A2500%0A4494%0A46552%0A75600&debug=0)**

### How does this work?

```
fqFmShMrPd8,QTh   ~ Full program. Q = first input.

f             h   ~ First input where the condition is truthy over [Q+1, Q+2, ...]
           ,QT    ~ The two element list [Q, current value (T)].
   m              ~ Map over ^ with d.
       Pd         ~ The prime factorization of d.
      r  8        ~ Run-Length encode ^.
    hM            ~ Get the first element of each.
 qF               ~ Check if the values are equal.
                  ~ Output implicitly.
```

---

### Alternatives

Another 15-byter:

```
LShMrPb8fqyQyTh
```

And a couple of (longer) alternatives:

```
fqFmSlM.gkPd,QTh
LSlM.gkPbfqyQyTh
LS/LPb{PbfqyQyTh
f!-FmlM.gkPd,QTh
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>176</s> <s>179</s> <s>171</s> <s>170</s> 169 bytes

- Added three bytes as the question changed from *set of exponents* to *list of exponents*; `set(f)` was changed to `sorted(f)`.
- Saved eight bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs); golfing the if / else block down to multiplication.
- Saved a byte; golfed `(n!=r)` to `(n>r)`.
- Saved a byte; golfed `while N>1` to `while~-N`.

```python
N=input();n=-~N
def F(N):
 r,f=0,[]
 while~-N:
	for n in range(2,-~N):
	 if N%n<1:f+=[1]*(n>r);f[-1]+=n==r;r=n;N/=n;break
 return sorted(f)
while F(N)!=F(n):n+=1
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU5BTsMwEDx3X7GNhGSTRDgmScFhuVTq0R@IcijUbiPQJjKugEu/Hkx7Gc2MZndm/o2nifWypSzLFksjz@coZMdUXiwcnMedsNIAhsKTKvoB8Ps0frpLaQ2s/BSQcWQMez46oYt0lMIrHD3aO36pjM@pr4Z7wa9Bdr4vqyEnJgpdIO7sQ4K34PYf6b@L58D4NYXoDsJLuNZc29e0EywN51TBHEaOyEta27kf957d1ijzL3CbLVqBblQCSKxSj0m1sGmfbm5dP9dQt02jYdO0Sv0B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
<.;?{ḋḅlᵐ}ᵐ=∧
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/30bP2r764Y7uhztacx5unVALxLaPOpb//29kavY/CgA)

It's been a long time since I posted an answer…

#### Explanation

```
<.               Input < Output
 .;?             The list [Output, Input]
    {    }ᵐ      Map on [Output, Input]:
     ḋ             Prime decomposition
      ḅ            Group into sublists of consecutive equal elements
       lᵐ          Take the length of each sublist
           =∧    The result of the map must be the same for the Output and the Input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 107 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
import Data.Numbers.Primes
p=sort.map(1<$).group.primeFactors
f x=until((==p x).p)(+1)$x+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcsxDgIhEEDRnlNMQQHZZBI6C@mMlTF7hdGwSoRlAkPC7XHtbP/Lf1P7hJTmjJlLFbiQEN5iE/Uf7j0/Qm241phDU@zbQZiJjTtri69aOiP/8EpPKbWpDYbvu8RkjPcMwyJbszirx@JmpriDh2PYBTRscJpf) Usage example: `f 2500` yields `2704`.

Thanks to nimi for pointing out a flaw and saving a bunch of bytes.

---

#### Without `primeFactors` build-in (117 bytes)

```hs
import Data.List
1%n=[]
x%n|0<-mod x n=n:div x n%n|m<-n+1=x%m
p=sort.map(1<$).group.(%2)
f x=until((==p x).p)(+1)$x+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEIDhPU9xQwIJocE4ifQ2R99AHAK1GkyuR5NKBt891u3ng/8VyvuRUu8x87JWuIQa3DWWKrwivN1FU/Q9jENeJmhASOcpfv61cx4Hsh6byoKx7LfLgbUfpXHPddnYaXU0YoaGG9WYtEZkaMax0dYb2azvOUQCBF4jVZAww6n/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python - 141 bytes

```
def s(n):
 i=1;d={}
 while n-1:
  i+=1
  if n%i<1:d[i]=d.get(i,0)+1;n/=i;i=1
 return d.values()
a=input()
j=a+1
while s(a)!=s(j):j+=1
print j
```

Comment: Your program seems to output the wrong value for `2500` as an input; `4624` instead of `2704`.

Comment: `while n-1:` can be `while~-n:`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes

```
XµN‚εÓ0K{}ËNI›&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v8wNWFiMWX//1jCtU7igJrOtcOTMEt7fcOLTknigLom//8yNTAw)

**Explanation**

```
Xµ                # Loop over N in [0 ...] until 1 match is found
  N‚              # pair N with input
    ε    }        # apply to each
     Ó            # list prime exponents
      0K          # remove zeroes
        {         # sort
          Ë       # check that they are equal
              &   # and
           NI›    # that N is greater than the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html), 118 bytes

```python
from sympy.ntheory import*
f=lambda k:sorted(factorint(k).values())
g=lambda i,k=2:i<k and f(k)==f(i)and k or g(i,k+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NczLDsIgEIXhfZ9iljNqGq27Rh4G5VJCYQhQE54e0cTl@fPlpFY3jvfeTeYApYXU5lg3zbmBC4lzPU1G7DI8lQS/lhG0QiNflbOLFT3Nb7kfuiDRZP/QXbxYVvfwIKMCM5QQBh19lwfOYHGQ8416@r1YXK5E/QM)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
>:@]^:(1--:&(_&q:/:~@-.0:))^:_>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY5BC4JAEIXv/oqHhO5C2uy2u9qEoQRB0CHqmklEEl0i6hb0122iw/cxvDcwcxviPO1RMVKMQWAhy7HcbVbDguv2yMpkGSeqSx484U@d5cRaH7lb8KCj1/n0vDxR5egs2gMsprAEW8LQVChgfUDwwaAIEtpSSk@ighycm4m8Ibjgvf25dCh8kAVDMlN0OV/vUGgxh1JVrz8TjbeccRghXTXrzbbZ79O4g44N/t9Ewxc)

Start from input + 1 `>:` and keep incrementing while the list of prime factors `_&q:` minus any zeros `-.0:`, then sorted `/:~@`, does not match `1--:`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
g=->m{m.prime_division.map{_2}.sort}
->n{((n+1)..).find{g[_1]==g[n]}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU5LDoIwEN1zikY3EEPTQn8uyk4uQQjRIKQLCilgYggX0Q2JuvJE3kbSspr3mzfzfJvxcv9mu9B0RjXXXf5Kpf8ZhyoUv1Mtw6SZGmitolQ31atWw-bcTUU0w741w-yFiZ58Xx9wAGEAK6XLqc4KnEtZZzqf563sEXgdSLMoB2APYoeRJZGwDKPYUoy4cymznFGGrcCZcIFIoC2BtgaOiFUIORKrEIpdhjBK3c0VCZfilG2LGK0ach8ui5t_)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Hideous! But I can't think of a better way :\

```
@[UX]Ëk ü mÊñÃre}aUÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QFtVWF3LayD8IG3K8cNyZX1hVcQ&input=MjUwMA)